# Java EE application deployment patterns books

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was wondering if there is any book or online resource available which can give me good overview of the Java EE deployment strategies on different servers. Or even a book which can tell me basics of Java EE application deployment.

Comment: Voted to close as this site is not meant to be a recommendation engine. Furthermore, 'deployment strategies' is fairly vague...